# Java command-line application somehow retains state

Tags: java, maven, command-line

*Foreword: I apologise if this is a very silly error or something that is in fact well-documented. To me right now it seems very strange and makes absolutely no sense.*

### The Application

I have a Java command-line application built in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate on macOS 10.13.4 that makes use of four Maven libraries listed below. Its purpose is to download files from a website, and navigates across paginated results in doing so.

One of this application's features is the ability to keep running in a loop, checking for new results if enough time has passed by the time it finishes its current scan. To do this, it calls `Thread.sleep(remainingMillis)` as part of the `while` condition in a do-while block.

### The Problem

The application worked without any issues, but after introducing the `Thread.sleep()` call (I suspect this is the troublesome line anyways), some very strange behaviour occurs: The application performs the first run without issues, fetching three items from the configured website; it is then configured to ensure that 60 seconds have passed before running again. However upon consequent runs, rather than scan the first page of results, logs indicate that it starts looking at page 31 (as an example), where it finds no results. Having failed to find anything, attempt two of three looks at page 32, and the final attempt looks at page 33; it then once again waits until 60 seconds have passed since the scan iteration began.

I can't confirm this, but it seems as though it then continues this count in subsequent scans: 34, 35, then 36, and waiting again. However, the code would suggest that this should have started at 1 again when another iteration of the `while` starts up.

This could have been IntelliJ or Java playing up, and it may have simply required cleaning out the bin/obj folders, but if this is something due to my code, I would much rather know about it so I don't encounter the same silly issue in the future.

### The Observations

Having just run the application a few days later with the current configuration means that it doesn't call `Thread.sleep()`, as more than 60 seconds pass so it continues with the next iteration immediately; when this happens, the weird page index incrementing issue doesn't rear its head - instead the next iteration continues from page 1 as it should.

Afterwards, running it such that it did `Thread.sleep()` for several seconds before starting the next iteration didn't cause a problem either... very strange. Was this a dream?

### The Code

*Sidenote:* I added `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` to try and fix this issue, but it didn't seem to have an effect.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int itemsFetched = startFetching(agent, config, record, 1, 0);
        } while (shouldRepeat(config.getRepeatSeconds(), startMillis));
    }

    private static boolean shouldRepeat(int repeatSeconds, long startMillis) {
        long passedMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis;
        int repeatMillis = repeatSeconds * 1000;
        boolean repeatSecondsReached = passedMillis >= repeatMillis;

        if (repeatSeconds < 0) {
            return false;
        } else if (repeatSecondsReached) {
            return true;
        }

        long remainingMillis = repeatMillis - passedMillis;
        int remainingSeconds = (int) (remainingMillis / 1000);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(remainingMillis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static int startFetching(Agenter agent, MyApplicationConfig config, MyApplicationRecord record, int pageIndex, int itemsFetched) {
        String categoryCode = config.getCategoryCode();
        List<Item> items = agent.getPageOfItems(categoryCode, pageIndex, config);

        if (items == null) {
            return itemsFetched;
        }

        int maxItems = config.getMaxItems();

        try {
            for (Item item : items) {
                String itemURL = item.getURL();

                agent.downloadItem(itemURL, config, item.getItemCount());
                itemsFetched++;

                if (maxItems > 0 && itemsFetched >= maxItems) {
                    return itemsFetched;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
           // Log
        }

        return startFetching(agent, config, record, pageIndex + 1, itemsFetched);
    }
}
```

#### Maven Libraries

- `commons-cli:commons-cli:1.4`
- `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.0`
- `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.0`
- `org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2`

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that this is easier to read / diagnose?

Comment: I’ve shortened the code significantly. Hopefully this is closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: You had extensive log statements, did the log not say which pageIndex it was using? My guess is it's related to the MyApplicationAgent class, which might store indices which on subsequent runs don't get reset.

Comment: So you are looping on a recursive method? Isn't that odd?

Comment: @AlimÖzdemir It did, but that was logging to console so I cannot check that now, which is how I knew that it was trying to access pages 31, 32, and 33 and some point. The `startFetching` method accepts a `pageIndex` which is set to 1 every time the top loop runs. Hence, I didn’t think that would be it but I may be wrong.

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy Perhaps odd, yes. I tried to be crafty with my control flow and may have been too crafty. Having said this, the recursive method call ends itself and collapses back through the call stack when enough items have been downloaded, which is what triggers the next do-while iteration. This next iteration calls `startFetching` with a `pageIndex` of 1, which is what confused me when it started sending out web requests for page indices of 31 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Agenter implementation, in the call of
 agent.getPageOfItems the pageIndex is supplied but could be stored there in an instance variable or something like that. The error itself might be that on additional calls it probably didn't get reset (correctly).